# How to add a space between list items in markdown?

Tags: markdown

How are dashes in `md` files rendered into `<ul><li>..</li><ul>`?
Is there a way to alter it into `<ul><li><p>..</p></li><ul>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [markdown documentation on lists](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

```
*   Bird
*   Magic
```

will turn into:

```
<ul>
<li>Bird</li>
<li>Magic</li>
</ul>
```

But this:

```
*   Bird

*   Magic
```

will turn into:

```
<ul>
<li><p>Bird</p></li>
<li><p>Magic</p></li>
</ul>
``
```

Comment: In a Jupyter Notebook it seems that one has to add _two_ empty lines between the list items in order to add the space.

Answer (score 0):

If using GitHub, it's also possible to add extra spacing (i.e., more than that added by leaving a blank line) by using html paragraphs:

```
  * Bird
    <p> <br> </p>
  * Magic
```

It's also possible to add arbitrary spacing (but always more than a paragraph) using math formulas, where all supported [LaTeX lengths](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lengths_in_LaTeX) can be used (pt, mm, cm, ...). For instance:

```
  * Bird
    <p> $\\[3cm]$ </p> 
  * Magic
```

Note that the html paragraph line should be aligned to the list item, as in the example.